# How do I scale the secondary axis properly using two Y axes

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I have created a plot showing the relationship between unemployment and earnings, however on the secondary axis for unemployment the line is not scaling properly, how would I fix this?

My code is:

```
ggplot(unemp_earn %>% filter(localauthority == "Glasgow City"), aes(x=date))+
  geom_line(aes(x=date, y=medianearnings), color="red")+
  geom_line(aes(x=date, y=unemploymentrate),color="blue")+
  scale_y_continuous("Median Earnings", sec.axis=sec_axis(~./50, name="Unemployment Rate"))
```

Which produces this graph:

[image]

Comment: You should pre-transform the data that should go on the secondary axis and do the inverse transform in the secondary axis. In your case, you'd have to multiply your unemployment rate by 50.